# Can we create object for private class

Tags: java, jsp, java-7, java-6

It is the basic doubt that  I am asking. Before asking here I asked with some of my colleagues and even with google but none returned me the answer which convinced me. So please anyone clarify my doubt. Thank you.

Comment: Very unclear: Are you trying to instantiate a private class? Something else?

Comment: Well, if you couldn't - what would be the use of a private class?

Comment: Yes trying to instantiate private class

Comment: @RajeshAcharya have you tried writing same, you will get compilation error for outer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. `private` is an access modifier, as you might have learned that restricts member to be access just within declaring scope. So as a member of another `class`, `private class` can be accessed in that class only.

Note that **the top level classes can never be private**

```
class Test {
private class TestInner{

}
....
TestInner ti = new TestInner();
....
}
```

Comment: So only for inner private class we can create objects for not for outer private class?

Comment: @RajeshAcharya: There is no outer private class. If you try, the compiler will tell you `Illegal modifier for the class YOURCLASSNAME; only public, abstract & final are permitted`.

Comment: @RajeshAcharya top level classes can  never be private